# Modification to axiom of infinity for the sake of asserting uniqueness?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I noticed that if one writes 
$$\exists X:(\varnothing\in X\space\wedge\space(n\in X\rightarrow n\cup \{n\}\in X)) $$
As the axiom of infinity, one must define The Natural numbers as the smallest set that satisfies the above condition. But by replacing the conditional with an iff, ie:
$$\exists\mathbb{N}!:(\varnothing\in\mathbb{N}\space\wedge\space(n\in\mathbb{N}\leftrightarrow n\cup\{n\}\in\mathbb{N}))$$
One could simply call the set proclaimed to exist and be unique above the natural numbers. Am I correct? Is there any reason that the Axiom of Infinity could not be replaced with this statement?

Comment: Even though this question has an easy negative answer, I hope it won't be downvoted. It's well formulated and allowed Henning to clear OP's confusion without any need for further clarification. (Which, unfortunately, is rare enough here on MSE.)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706661/why-is-the-infinite-set-from-the-axiom-of-infinity-the-natural-numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your proposed condition does not define $\mathbb N$ uniquely.

For example, it is also satisfied by $V_\omega$, the set of all *hereditarily finite sets*.

---

We *could* take as an axiom that there exists **an inductive set that has no inductive proper subset**, and *that* would be unique. But that seems just to be added complexity that doesn't really buy us anything, given that we have the axiom of separation available *anyway*.

Alternatively we could take:
$$\exists X: X=\{\varnothing\}\cup \{n\cup\{n\}\mid n\in X\}$$
which *in the presence of the Axion of Regularity* would pinpoint $\omega$ uniquely. (It is clearly inductive, and if $Y$ is any inductive subset of it, then $Y=X$, or else $X\setminus Y$ would violate Regularity).

Comment: Furthermore, given that we work in something that resembles $\operatorname{ZF}$, we have that for any infinite set $X$ there is some $X \subseteq Y$ such that there is a bijection $f \colon X \to Y$ and $Y$ is such that $y \in Y \leftrightarrow y \cup \{y \} \in Y$ - by a simple closure argument.

Comment: @Stefan: I think you need some form of choice for that. If $X$ is [amorphous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set), it cannot have your property.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks!

Comment: The OP's proposed condition is also satisfied by any non-zero limit ordinal.